# How to split and arrange a JS object]with multiple data points [arrays]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS object that is store in a variable (var groups) like this this:

console.log(groups)

```
0: "Abejales,275"
1: "Acarigua,238"
2: "Achaguas,38"
3: "Agua Blanca,231"
4: "Aguasay,208"
5: "Altagracia de Orituco,146"
6: "Anaco,17"
7: "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
```

I need to split this into two different variables: var gr_1 and var gr_2 and I need to get something like this:

console.log(gr_1)

```
0: "Abejales"
1: "Acarigua"
2: "Achaguas"
3: "Agua Blanca"
4: "Aguasay"
5: "Altagracia de Orituco"
6: "Anaco"
7: "Aragua de Barcelona"
```

console.log(gr_2)

```
0: "275"
1: "238"
2: "38"
3: "231"
4: "208"
5: "146"
6: "17"
7: "18"
```

I tried doing this, but it doesn't work

```
var [gr_a, gr_b] = groups.split(',');
console.log(gr_a)
console.log(gr_b)
```

Comment: is `groups` an array or an obejct with numerical keys?

Comment: var groups = d3.set(data.neurons.map(function(d) { return [d.description_n4, d.id]} ).sort()).values() 
(description_n4 is text and id is an identifier of the descripction)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// if this is an array

let groups = ["Abejales,275",
  "Acarigua,238",
  "Achaguas,38",
  "Agua Blanca,231",
  "Aguasay,208",
  "Altagracia de Orituco,146",
  "Anaco,17",
  "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
]

// reduce() is very useful for classifying things - 
// you can initialize it with anything (like [] or {})
// and then you can create the classes you want
groups = groups.reduce((a, c) => {
  // destructuring the array created with split(',')
  const [gr_1, gr_2] = c.split(',')
  a[0].push(gr_1)
  a[1].push(gr_2)
  return a
}, [
  [],
  []
])

console.log('Array:', groups)
const gr_1 = groups[0]
const gr_2 = groups[1]

// if this is an object

let groupsObj = {
  0: "Abejales,275",
  1: "Acarigua,238",
  2: "Achaguas,38",
  3: "Agua Blanca,231",
  4: "Aguasay,208",
  5: "Altagracia de Orituco,146",
  6: "Anaco,17",
  7: "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
}

const grObj_1 = []
const grObj_2 = []

// using Object.values to iterate over the values if the
// the object
for (let val of Object.values(groupsObj)) {
  // destructuring the array created with split(',')
  const [gr_1, gr_2] = val.split(',')
  grObj_1.push(gr_1)
  grObj_2.push(gr_2)
}

console.log("object:", grObj_1, grObj_2)
```

```html
0: "Abejales,275" 1: "Acarigua,238" 2: "Achaguas,38" 3: "Agua Blanca,231" 4: "Aguasay,208" 5: "Altagracia de Orituco,146" 6: "Anaco,17" 7: "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
```

Here's another one that's cool with arrays and objects:

```js
function twoGroups(group) {
  return group.reduce((a, c) => {
    const [gr_1, gr_2] = c.split(',')
    a[0].push(gr_1)
    a[1].push(gr_2)
    return a
  }, [
    [],
    []
  ])
}

const [grArr_1, grArr_2] = twoGroups([
  "Abejales,275",
  "Acarigua,238",
  "Achaguas,38",
  "Agua Blanca,231",
  "Aguasay,208",
  "Altagracia de Orituco,146",
  "Anaco,17",
  "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
])

console.log('arrays:', grArr_1, grArr_2)

const [grObj_1, grObj_2] = twoGroups(Object.values({
  0: "Abejales,275",
  1: "Acarigua,238",
  2: "Achaguas,38",
  3: "Agua Blanca,231",
  4: "Aguasay,208",
  5: "Altagracia de Orituco,146",
  6: "Anaco,17",
  7: "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
}))

console.log('objects:', grObj_1, grObj_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this behavior using `reduce` method.

```
const [gr_1, gr_2] = data.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
  const [text, number] = value.split(',');
  accumulator[0].push(text);
  accumulator[1].push(number);
  return accumulator;
}, [[], []]),;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over you object element then `split` by `,`. Like below example.

```js
var groups = {
  0: "Abejales,275",
  1: "Acarigua,238",
  2: "Achaguas,38",
  3: "Agua Blanca,231",
  4: "Aguasay,208",
  5: "Altagracia de Orituco,146",
  6: "Anaco,17",
  7: "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
}
var gr_a =  [], gr_b = [];
for(index in groups) {
  const splits = groups[index].split(',');
  gr_a = [...gr_a, splits[0]];
  gr_b = [...gr_b, splits[1]];
}
console.log({...gr_a });
console.log({ ...gr_b });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var groups = {
 0: "Abejales,275",
 1: "Acarigua,238",
 2: "Achaguas,38",
 3: "Agua Blanca,231",
 4: "Aguasay,208",
 5: "Altagracia de Orituco,146",
 6: "Anaco,17",
 7: "Aragua de Barcelona,18"
}

var gr_1 = {};
var gr_2 = {};
var tempArr = Object.values(groups);
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
    gr_1[x] = tempArr[i].split(",")[0];
    gr_2[y] = tempArr[i].split(",")[1];
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
}

console.log(gr_1);
console.log(gr_2);
```